# How to do something if a job has finished

Tags: powershell, jobs

I'm trying to implement a GUI to my PowerShell script to simplify a certain process for other users. I have following PowerShell script:

```
if ($checkBox1.Checked)    { 
    Try{
    Start-Job { & K:\sample\adp.cmd }
    $listBox1.Items.Add("ADP-Job started...")
    }catch [System.Exception]{
    $listBox1.Items.Add("ADP --> .cmd File not found!")}
    }

    if ($checkBox2.Checked)    { 
    Try{ 
    Start-Job { & K:\sample\kdp.cmd }
    $listBox1.Items.Add("KDP-Job started...")
    }catch [System.Exception]{
    $listBox1.Items.Add("KDP --> .cmd File not found!")}
    }
```

Is there a way to continuously check all running Jobs and do something for each Job that has finished? For Example to print out something like this in my listbox: `ADP-Files have been uploaded`

Since each Job takes around 5 minutes - 4 hours I thought of a while Loop that checks every 5 minutes if a Job is finished, but I can't figure out how to distinguish each Job to do something specific.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can either specifiy a name for the job using the `-Name` parameter:

```
Start-Job { Write-Host "hello"} -Name "HelloWriter"
```

And receive the job status using the `Get-Job` cmdlet:

```
Get-Job -Name HelloWriter
```

**Output:**

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
3      HelloWriter     BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost             Write-Host "hello"
```

---

Or you assign the `Start-Job` cmdlet to a variable and use it to retrieve the job:

```
$worldJob = Start-Job { Write-Host "world"}
```

So you can just write `$woldJob` and receive:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
7      Job7            BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost             Write-Host "world"
```

You also don't have to poll the Job state. Instead use the `Register-ObjectEvent` cmdlet to get notificated when the job has finished:

```
$job = Start-Job { Sleep 3; } -Name "HelloJob"

$jobEvent = Register-ObjectEvent $job StateChanged -Action {
    Write-Host ('Job #{0} ({1}) complete.' -f $sender.Id, $sender.Name)
    $jobEvent | Unregister-Event
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. So if i give my Jobs individual names and then use the Get-Job -Name cmdlet i can create a custom message to print out once the Job has been completed, even though it takes a few hours? Or would i have to make a Loop that continuously checks every 5 minutes if it's completed?

Comment: You could also let the job himself output a message after he is finished

Comment: That would be the perfect solution but how would i do that? i tried it by putting a write-host message behind my .cmd file but it just imidiatly printed the message, even though the Job hasn't finished yet.

Comment: I found a better solution, see my edited answer. I think thats the best way to do that

Comment: Thank you so much! This is amazing, just what i searched for.

Comment: `$jobEvent | Unregister-Event` does not seem to work the way I believe you intended it. After running this example, there is still a job in running state.

Comment: @MartinBrandl I was trying to use the above code. $job gets perfectly removed. However, I see that jobEvent still keeps "Running". Is there a way the jobEvent can be removed too?

Answer (score 5):

Multiple possible ways here:

```
$Var = Start-Job { & K:\sample\kdp.cmd }
```

an then check

```
$Var.State
```

Or give the job a name

```
Start-Job { & K:\sample\kdp.cmd } -Name MyJob
```

and then check

```
Get-Job MyJob
```